# How to aggregate synonym data with SPARQL

Tags: aggregate, sparql

I'm using sesame repository with some triple data publication like this:

```
<http://example.org/doc2> a qb:Observation;
   foaf:Organization "Inst. of Technol.";
   ps:sumPaper 3 .

<http://example.org/doc3> a qb:Observation;
   foaf:Organization "Institute of Technology";
   ps:sumPaper 5 .

<http://example.org/doc4> a qb:Observation;
   foaf:Organization "Dong C Univ.";
   ps:sumPaper 4 .

<http://example.org/doc5> a qb:Observation;
   foaf:Organization "University of Dong C";
   ps:sumPaper 2 .
```

doc2 and doc3, actually have the same organization. As well as doc 4 and doc 5, its has synonym organization.
I want to aggregate data with sparql, and I want to expect result like this :

```
   Organization              sumPaper 
   -----------------------------------
    Insitute of Technology      8  
    University of Dong C        6
```

so, I added at repository with synonym ontology to description.

```
 :org2 a foaf:Organization;
     ps:organizationName "Inst. of Technol";   
     owl:sameAs :org3.

:org3 a foaf:Organization;
     ps:organizationName "Institute of Technology".

:org4 a foaf:Organization;
     ps:organizationName "Dong C Univ.";

:org5 a foaf:Organization;
    ps:organizationName "University of Dong C";
    owl:sameAs :org4.
```

please help me...I'm so confused to make sparql statement to get result that I expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're complicating things with `owl:sameAs`, Try this instead:

```
:org1 a foaf:Organization ;
     ps:organizationName "Inst. of Technol", "Institute of Technology" .

:org2 a foaf:Organization ;
     ps:organizationName "Dong C Univ.", "University of Dong C" .
```

You can then do the following:

```
select ?org (SUM(?sumP) as ?sum)
{
    ?ob a qb:Observation ;
        ps:sumPaper ?sumP ;
        foaf:Organization ?orgName .

    # Lookup org based on synonyms
    ?org ps:organizationName ?orgName .
}
group by ?org
```

Although that will give you org identifiers. If that bothers you:

```
select (SAMPLE(?orgName) as ?name) (SUM(?sumP) as ?sum)
...
```

or even add an `rdsf:label` or `skos:prefLabel` to each org in your synonym file.

Comment: thank you @user205512 .. you really help me. I'm little confused with owl:sameAs. I try your suggest.. and it's work. :)

Comment: If you were using a store with OWL inferencing my query would pretty much work with your synonym file (you'd find a lot of duplication, though, but basically the right answer). The two synonym files are essentially equivalent *but* you need owl inferencing for it to work, or a more complex query which does the same work,